# Oracle SQL - Group by function list the same year more than once

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select extract( year from "date" ),count(id)    
  from table1 e 
  left join table2 w
    on e.differentid = w.differentid -- (different id is in both tables, ‘id’ is not)    
 where regexp_like(id, '^[[:digit:]]+$')    
 group by "date", extract( year from "date" )
 order by "date";
```

I'm using the above code to create a table with 3 fields. One with the year, one with a count of IDs that only contain numbers and one of count IDs that contain numbers and letters.

The group by doesn't make it a single row per year but years appear multiple times.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. In your case: `GROUP BY extract (year from "date")`.

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating by `date`.  You need to remove that from the `group by`:

```
select extract(year from date),
       sum(case when REGEXP_LIKE(id, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then 1 else 0 end ) as only_digits,
       sum(case when REGEXP_LIKE(id, '^[[:alpha:][:digit:]]+$') then 1 else 0 end ) as only_alphadigits,
from table1 e left join
     table2 w
     on e.differentid = w.differentid  -- (different id is in both tables, ‘id’ is not)    
group by extract(year from date)
order by min(DATE);
```

The keys in the `group by` define the rows in the result set.  Each unique combination of key values results in *one* row in the result set.  Clearly, there are multiple rows for a `date` within a "year".  By including `date`, you are getting each row individually.

Comment: would you be able to advise on the third field, counting IDs witch contain letters and numbers within the same query

Comment: @arsenaql  . . . That uses conditional aggregation.